# iphone - UI Unit Testing?

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, ui-testing

When it comes to writing unit testing for UI what do you write test for?

- Do you test each method? (EX: a method returns the correct data)
- Or do you test the functionalities? (Making sure that the table populates the data it suppose to)

Do I need to mock everything except the item I am testing? Let's say I am testing to make sure a table view populates correctly? Do i mock everything else?

**Please provide as much details as possibe**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer this in a general way.
When testing UI-ish code it's often a good idea to target the tests "one step away" from the UI itself.  Ex. run against the models instead of the UI itself if possible.  It's much less brittle this way.  I'm not familiar with iOS UI test automation but these sort of things tend to break upon the smallest layout changes etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you take a look at [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) by Gorilla Logic. They have a very nice utility for writing unit test which actually tests from the users perspective, aka. check that the UI is as it should be, ie. loads correctly, contains the correct values, etc.

You can even run it in a faceless environment, eg. Continuous Integration server, etc.